# argument name in prototype method (variable name in header function)

Tags: c++, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should function declarations include parameter names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891526/should-function-declarations-include-parameter-names)

In a C++ header file, you need to give the function prototype's name, return type and arguments' types. You need not specify the names for the arguments.
Example:

```
double fraction(double numerator, double denominator);
```

vs

```
double fraction(double, double);
```

Is there an advantage in writing an argument's name? Readability?
Is there any difference for compiling, or for efficiency, or else?

Comment: You're right @Benj, I couldn't find a similar question but you did, thanks. Well, perhaps someone comes with a compiling/efficiency/something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference in compilation. (May be parsing of later will be fast as it has to parse less code, but who cares about that?).

The big advantage is in readability. In second case how can the user differentiate between which is numerator and which is denominator?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for keeping the argument names in the header file is for consistency and readability.  If you have a policy of removing them then you can no longer copy/paste the declarations from your cpp file.

If you're using a documentation engine like doxygen, that might also provide you a cogent reason to keep parameter names since documentation engines tend to parse headers and will provide nicer output if you've included the names of the parameters.

Other than this, there is no strict reason to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

No difference in efficiency. Omitting the name in header should be synced with omitting it in implementation file. There you can omit it, if your impl does not use that arg, and then everybody can see by looking at the parameter-list wether an arg is used or not (And some compilers give warning when an arg has a name, but isn't used in implementation. Hope that helps...

Comment: "Synced with omitting in implementation?" It won't work if I omit in implementation. I probably misunderstood you, could you please rephrase?

Comment: omitting in the implementation works then, if the parameter is not used there. But its always a good idea to still have the parameter-name there as comment, e.g. void x (int /*theUsefulNameOfThisInt*/) {...}

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you put them there so someone looking at the header understands the purpose of those parameters.