# Is it a good practice to omit parameter names in declarations?

Tags: c++, coding-style

With parameter names:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    someType f(someType parameterName);
};
```

Without Parameter names:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    someType f(someType);
};
```

In terms of C++, which one is recommended? Or just a personal preference?

Comment: Personally I find it annoying because you have to look up the documentation if you only have access to the declarations. i.e., `(int, int)` is not informative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should function declarations include parameter names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891526/should-function-declarations-include-parameter-names)

Comment: I have rarely seen unnamed parameters.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow (opinion based).

Comment: I agree with @remyabel. Code that includes parameter names is more self-documenting.

Comment: When googling this question, I didn't find out any thread similar. What do I do now? Delete this one? Or just leave it here?

Comment: I would omit name in declaration when it is absent in implementation  (unused parameter...) to be consistent.

Comment: apart maybe from Jarod's answer I would say never omit it. omission is an abomination left over from C history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any advantage in omitting the names from the declaration.
On the other hand, I do see several disadvantages:

1. Your code is less readable.
2. Your intention is less clear.
3. It gets a lot more messy to get the code to work ("wait a second, why does `PowerOf2("10,2");` Gives me `1024`? I was expecting `100`.")