# (C++) Copy constructor without parameter argument name

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I am having some trouble figuring out how certain types of constructors work in C++.
I was given an example class called Vector, that looks something like this:

```
class Vector {
   double* vData;
   size_t n_element;
   static size_t defS;
public:
   //bunch of other constructors and this one:
   Vector(const Vector&);
}
```

As I gather this is a copy constructor, but without the name, how can I access the passed Vector's variables and functions?
I thought it's usually declared in a manner like this:

> Vector(const Vector& obj);

So what is the difference and how can I access the object variables in the first case?

Comment: Declaration != Definition. In definition, it would have a name to be able to use it. In declaration, it is not needed.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Should function declarations include parameter names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7891526/10871073)

Answer (score 0):

`Vector(const Vector&);` is a *declaration* of a constructor and it has the same meaning as `Vector(const Vector& obj);`.

You should assign parameter name when *defining* the constructor to receive the value:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& v) {
    // do something using v
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Vector(const Vector&);
```

is merely the declaration of the method. Even with a name for the parameter added, you cannot "access" it, because the declaration has no body. Names of parameters are optional on declarations.

On the definition you use the name as usual:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& other) {
     // use other 
}
```