# Is there a reason to name parameters in forward declaration?

Tags: c++

Say I have this:

```
// Forward Declaration of the sum()
void sum(int, int);

// Usage of the sum
void sum(int a, int b)
{
    // Body
}
```

It could also be done like this:

```
// Forward Declaration of the sum()
void sum(int a, int b);

// Usage of the sum
void sum(int a, int b)
{
    // Body
}
```

Is the latter version just a waste of space?  I see it both ways.

Comment: No there isn't, besides giving clarity what the parameters should mean.

Comment: If the forward declaration is in a header or otherwise far away from the definition it can be very informative, particularly with descriptive identifiers. Sometimes a well written header is all the documentation you need (and might be all you get).

Comment: It makes the code much more readable and self documenting.

Comment: `sum` returning `void` is suspect ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/7891526/4117728. Whether its a forward doesnt matter that much. Afaik "forward declaration" isnt even an official term. A forward declaration is just a declaration

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: The reasonable interpretation here is that a "forward declaration" is not a definition. It's pretty clear why parameter names are useful to definitions.

Comment: @MSalters sorry I dont understand what you mean. I was just trying to explain that the other answer is basically asking about the same thing, even though it asks whether names should be placed on declarations in headers and here OP is asking about forward declaration. I don't think it makes a big difference (well some of the arguments in the other question like doc generation does not apply for forward declarations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to.

You could even rename your function to

```
void _(int, int);
```

(in both places of course). But then it's harder to follow still. In other words the parameter and function names are important for readability. Given most program documentation appears in header files, and most forward declarations are in header files, it makes sense to include the function parameter names as used in the function definition.

Remember that program source code has two users. The compiler is one, the programmer is the other.

Comment: That would be a forward declaration of the function named `_`, not of `sum`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Sorry not clear really is it? I'll probably delete. Just tying to make a point - not particularly well?